# Possible to find expression for the energy of mixing with the Helmholtz free Energy?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I am aware that the energy of mixing can be found using the thermodynamic identity for the Gibbs free Energy and plugging in the expression for the entropy of mixing which finds;-∆G_Mixing≈-T*N*k (xlnx+(1-x)ln⁡(1-x)) with particles of type A: N_A= (1-x)N and type B: N_B= xN. I was wondering if, when the temperature, number of particles and volume (one type of the particles being in a much greater presence) is held constant, the Helmholtz free energy could be used to find the energy of mixing?